# Why is it possible to pass in a non-function parameter to Promise.then() without causing an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following:

```
new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
    .then(() => console.log("after 2 seconds"));

new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))
    .then(console.log("before 3 seconds (instantly)"));
```

which produces the following output:

```
> node index.js
before 3 seconds (instantly)
after 2 seconds
```

[Promise.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) expects a `onFulfilled` function, but I passed in `console.log("before 2 seconds (instantly)")`, which is not a function. Two-part question:

- Why does `console.log("before 2 seconds (instantly)")` get executed right away (or at all)?
- Why didn't the second Promise raise an exception when I didn't pass in a function?

Comment: "Why does console.log("before 2 seconds (instantly)") get executed right away (or at all)?" Why *wouldn't* it get executed instantly? Before the result of an expression can be passed as an argument, it needs to be evaluated. In this case, evaluating `console.log("before 3 seconds (instantly)")` results in stuff being logged to the console, followed by the `undefined` result being used as an argument for invoking `Promise#then`.

Comment: Did [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094764/why-is-it-possible-to-pass-in-a-non-function-parameter-to-promise-then-without/42094874#42094874) answer your questions? Any comments?

Answer (score 7):

The code

```
console.log("before 3 seconds (instantly)")
```

is an **expression**, specifically a function call expression. Wherever that appears, it means the same thing, including an appearance as an argument to the `.then()` method of a Promise. As in any other similar language, an expression used in a function call is evaluated *before* the function call, so

```
.then(console.log("before 3 seconds (instantly)"))
```

results in the `console.log()` function being called **first**, with the return value then passed to `.then()`. That's why you see the message in the console immediately.

Passing `undefined` to `.then()` is allowed, and since that's what `console.log()` returns, there's no error raised.

If you want that `console.log()` to happen when the Promise is fulfilled, you'd wrap it in a function:

```
.then(function() { console.log("after 3 seconds"); })
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why is it possible to pass in a non-function parameter to Promise.then() without causing an error?

Yes. All non-function arguments should be ignored. See below.

> Why does console.log("before 2 seconds (instantly)") get executed right away (or at all)?

Because in JS the arguments to functions calls are evaluated instantly (applicative order).

> Why didn't the second Promise raise an exception when I didn't pass in a function?

Because `console.log` returns `undefined` and `.then()` with no arguments is legal (because both handlers are optional). In your example `console.log()` returns undefined so it is like calling `.then()` with no arguments.

But even if it was called with some arguments that are not functions, they would still get ignored. For example even in this example the 'ok' would still get to the `console.log` at the end, which may be surprising:

```
Promise.resolve('ok')
    .then()
    .then(false)
    .then(null)
    .then(1)
    .then('x')
    .then([1, 2, 3])
    .then({a: 1, b: 2})
    .then(console.log);
```

See the [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) specification, section 2.2.1 that describe the arguments to the `.then()` method:

> 2.2.1 Both onFulfilled and onRejected are optional arguments:
>
> - If onFulfilled is not a function, it must be ignored.
> - If onRejected is not a function, it must be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does `console.log("before 2 seconds (instantly)")` get executed right away (or at all)?

A function's parameters are evaluated before the function is called. When you do `alert(1+2)` you expect `1+2` to be evaluated first, and when you do `alert(console.log("..."))` you should likewise expect `console.log("...")` to be evaluated first. There's nothing special about `then`; it's just a regular function and its arguments are treated the same as any other function's arguments.

> Why didn't the second Promise raise an exception when I didn't pass in a function?

Because `console.log` returns `undefined`, and the language specification ([ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen)) says what should happen when you call `then(undefined)`, and it's not throwing an exception. Let's look at what it does say:

> #### [25.4.5.3.1 PerformPromiseThen ( promise, onFulfilled, onRejected, resultCapability )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen)
>
> The abstract operation PerformPromiseThen performs the “then”
>   operation on *promise* using *onFulfilled* and *onRejected* as its
>   settlement actions. The result is *resultCapability*’s promise.
>
> 1. Assert: IsPromise(*promise*) is **true**.
> 2. Assert: *resultCapability* is a PromiseCapability record.
> 3. If IsCallable(*onFulfilled*) is **false**, then
>
>    1. Let *onFulfilled* be **`"Identity"`**.
> 4. If IsCallable(*onRejected*) is **false**, then
>
>    1. Let *onRejected* be **`"Thrower"`**.
> 5. Let *fulfillReaction* be the PromiseReaction { [[Capabilities]]: *resultCapability*, [[Handler]]: *onFulfilled* }.
> 6. ...

The salient points here are (3) and (5). In (3), since *onFulfilled* is `undefined`, IsCallable(*onFulfilled*) is **false** and so *onFulfilled* is set to **`"Identity"`**. Then, in (5), a PromiseReaction is created with the [[Handler]] *onFulfulled*, which we know is **`"Identity"`**.

Here's what the section [PromiseReaction Records](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promisereaction-records) says about **`"Identity"`**:

> If [[Handler]] is **`"Identity"`** it is equivalent to a function that simply returns its first argument.

So there you have it. Calling `then(undefined)` is basically the same as calling `then(a => a)`, which is why you don't get an error.